# How can I automatically delete all whitespace on empty lines and all trailing whitespace on non-empty lines?

Tags: autocmd

I'm using the `flake8` linter for Python, which constantly complains about whitespace on empty lines and trailing whitespace on non-empty lines.

How can I configure Vim to automatically remove such whitespace, e.g. whenever I save the file?

Is there any good plugin for performing this operation?